# Keyboard in a popup webview is not showing

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, popup

I'm having some issues with a pop up that shows a WebView in Android. 
The pop up works fine, but when I try to write something, the keyboard doesn't show up.
It's a chat so the keyboard part is pretty important :P
Here's my pop up code:

```
public void showPopUp(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Chat YEAH 107.5");

            WebView wv = new WebView(this);
            wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            wv.loadUrl("http://190.171.0.181:3000/");
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            alert.setView(wv);
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cerrar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
}
```

And my manifest file(at least the part of the activity description):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.racsa.UI.VideoViewDemo"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="Media/VideoView"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

There's no output or anything like that.. Or errors.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after several days stuck with this issue, I figured out a way to still make the popup thing, but without using the dialog.
I put the webview that handles the chat loading like a popup, but invisible, so when I touch the open chat option, looks like a popup, coming from the center of the layout.
I know is not as cool as the popup, but it certainly does the work!
Thanks anyway!